# Referencing a Main Form control in a different class

Tags: vb.net

I am a hobby programmer in VB.Net.  Have fairly good knowledge in that.  However I got stuck in a place I need help.

1. I have a main form called BTC_Main
2. I have a different class called ClientID
3. I would like to refer to the main form control in Client ID class file
4. My Line in client ID "BTC_Main.Lvw_ClientID" gives an error "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Even though its C# this will explain how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/13537851/495455

Comment: The control is ListView Control.  I am using VS 2019.

Comment: Forms are just classes, and like any class you could have many instances. You need to tell it which instance of the class you want.

Comment: Use the `Application.OpenForms` collection. In particular look at `OfType()`. This will help  you to get a reference to the form, assuming it is open.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69743297/10024425

Comment: I added the line     Public Shared BTC_Main As Object in the ClientID class and the error went off.

Comment: _and the error went off_.  If that's the case, update your question with the actual code and details of what this error was and where encounter.

Comment: The error did go off in that class.  However a new problems are arising and I am working on them.  Once completed, would be too happy share the solution.

Comment: Putting the line "Public Shared BTC_Main As Object" in more than one module generated problems and I could not access the form design at all. As I said I had removed the line "Public Shared BTC_Main As Object" in all the classes. I brought all references to main form control to main form class.  Now no problem.